# Как можно создать N файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно создать N файлов. Число N будет вводить пользователи?

Comment: С чем конкретно возникли затруднения? Что вам мешает решить задачу самостоятельно?

Comment: Я не могу создать количество файлов, который вводить пользователи

Comment: Это обычная задачка на знание/закрипление циклов. А так же работу с filter/map/reduce
посмотрите как в питоне можно построить обычный цикл for i in [0, N-1] и в теле цикла создавайте файл(отдельно поищите информацию о создании и записи файлов в питоне), содержащий M случайных цифр(так же оищите как генерировать рандомные значения в питоне)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
n = int(input())

for i in range(1, n+1):
    open(f'file_{i}.txt', 'w').close()
```